# Php Curl live server not working

Tags: php, api, curl

I test the script on my localhost and it working perfectly. I tried on my the live server and it didn't work.

```
<?php
   $uploadfile=dirname(__FILE__)."/xml_request/cat.xml"; 
   $ch = curl_init("http://remote.xxxxxxxxxx.com.au:8090/Options.API");   
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
               array('Request'=>"@$uploadfile",
                     'clientKey'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '8090');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $postResult = curl_exec($ch);

   $response = curl_getinfo($ch);
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($response);
   echo "</pre>";

   curl_close($ch);
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($postResult);
   //file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/xml_record/live.xml', $postResult);

?>
```

Localhost
I print_r the curl_getinfo($ch).

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://remote.xxxxxxxx.com.au:8090/Options.API
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 246
    [request_size] => 215
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 2.278
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.344
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.344
    [download_content_length] => 9376
    [upload_content_length] => 759
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.734
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Live test 
I print_r the curl_getinfo($ch).

```
 Array
    (
        [url] => http://remote.xxxxxxxxxxx.com.au:8090/Options.API
        [content_type] => 
        [http_code] => 0
        [header_size] => 0
        [request_size] => 0
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0.012024
        [namelookup_time] => 0.011809
        [connect_time] => 0
        [pretransfer_time] => 0
        [download_content_length] => -1
        [upload_content_length] => -1
        [starttransfer_time] => 0
        [redirect_time] => 0
    )
```

Not sure if the port of the url is the problem. I try to search to solve the problem but no luck.

Comment: Is there a firewall on your server blocking outbound traffic on port `8090`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that and where.

Comment: There any way? to unblock the port or something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I contact the support of the hosting. I said that unblock the port 8090. Thanks for giving me the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Comments:

Your webhost is probably blocking outbound traffic on port 8090. Many webhosts block uncommon ports for added security. The only way to get this resolved is to contact your webhost and ask them to unblock the port so that you can connect on it.