# paypal pro curl not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal AngellEYE library.
I test the script on my localhost and it working perfectly. I tried on my the live server and it didn't work.
When
in DoDirectPayment method

```
function CURLRequest($Request = "", $APIName = "", $APIOperation = "")
{
    $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->EndPointURL);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Request);

    if($this->APIMode == 'Certificate')
    {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $this->PathToCertKeyPEM);
    }
    $Response = curl_exec($curl);
    $r = curl_getinfo($curl)    ;
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($Response); 
    die;    
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Localhost I print_r the curl_getinfo($ch).

```
TIMESTAMP=2015%2d09%2d29T06%3a50%3a14Z&CORRELATIONID=a574165dd749a&ACK=Success&VERSION=98%2e0&BUILD=000000&AMT=35%2e00&CURRENCYCODE=USD&AVSCODE=X&CVV2MATCH=M&TRANSACTIONID=8KK333442W014904SArray
(
[url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
[content_type] => text/plain; charset=utf-8
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 413
[request_size] => 1014
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 20
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 16.646
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0.328
[pretransfer_time] => 0.952
[size_upload] => 876
[size_download] => 189
[speed_download] => 11
[speed_upload] => 52
[download_content_length] => 189
[upload_content_length] => 876
[starttransfer_time] => 16.646
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => 173.0.82.83
[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 192.168.1.8
[local_port] => 54396
[redirect_url] => 
)
```

Live test I print_r the curl_getinfo($ch).

```
Array
(
[url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0.211927
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => 173.0.82.83
[redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: there is your redirect_url is blank in the response check in your requesting post data is contain success url  and  cancel url

Comment: but in local server payment success full without redirect_url

Comment: there is a similar question about curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777216/php-curl-live-server-not-working

Comment: another similar question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877703/curl-script-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-live-server